# django: compare and decrement without race conditions

Tags: django

I'm trying to compare a value and decrement it without race conditions. The following code is not correct because "stock" could be modified in both the conditional and the assignment.

```
if product.stock >= requested:
    product.stock -= requested
    product.save()
else:
    raise Error("Product not available")
```

I read about F() expressions to prevent race conditions.

```
if product.stock >= requested:
    product.stock = F('stock') - requested
    product.save()
else:
    raise Error("Product not available")
```

This is better, but the conditional is still prone to race conditions. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could use select_for_update() to lock the row you are updating. This will take care of the race condition dilemma.

Comment: @almostabeginner As you metioned it is better if you had linked the docs. Any ways @Valar Find the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) and how `select_for_update` behaves.



**All matched entries will be locked until the end of the transaction block, meaning that other transactions will be prevented from changing or acquiring locks on them. Usually, if another transaction has already acquired a lock on one of the selected rows, the query will block until the lock is released.**

Comment: Yea, i'm using my outdated phone so it would be a mission to change tabs and link the docs. I just wanted to leave him/her with a quick suggestion. @thulasiram